# Django SECRET_KEY environmental variable always empty

Tags: python, django, windows, environment-variables

In mysite/settings.py I have:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ["SECRET_KEY"]
```

Using the GUI Control Panel ---> System Properties ---> Advanced ---> Environmental Variables, I have set the user environmental variables:

```
Variable            Value
SECRET_KEY          123456
```

But am still getting the key is empty error when I run manage.py

```
Failed to get real commands on module "mysite": python process died with code 1: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1.2\plugins\python\helpers\pycharm\_jb_manage_tasks_provider.py", line 25, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\super\Desktop\GitHub\Django_Tutorial_Site\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\Users\super\Desktop\GitHub\Django_Tutorial_Site\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\super\Desktop\GitHub\Django_Tutorial_Site\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\super\Desktop\GitHub\Django_Tutorial_Site\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\super\Desktop\GitHub\Django_Tutorial_Site\mysite\mysite\settings.py", line 11, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ["SECRET_KEY"]
  File "C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

Comment: Try launching a Django Shell from your cmd while in your virtual env. Then `import os` and run `os.environ` to see all your variables. If it is not in there, you might need to set it at the system level instead of the user level.

Comment: did you restart the cmd/powershell?

Comment: @sohail288  Thanks, I had to restart PyCharm. It doesn't re-discover environmental variables otherwise.